# how to force https

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-controller

I have a grails project.  Right now, the user can access it either with HTTP or HTTPS.  I would like to require that they can only access it through HTTPS.  any ideas? I do have spring security core installed, if that can be of help

thanks
jason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring's core supports that:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
  '/path/**':         'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
]
```

Comment: Check out Chapter 17 at http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/

Comment: Thanks for the response  what file does this go into?  UrlMappings.groovy?

Comment: `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` is where app-specific configurations go.

Comment: thanks again.  follow up question.  if i want to make all pages require https, is this possible?  or do i need to list every controller?

Comment: Just remove the `/path` part, making it `'/**'`.

Comment: Thanks!  I have one more question but will post in a new thread

Comment: @ChrisCashwell  
I tried adding this line, but now I get an error "This webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". Any ideas?

Comment: @dead_jake, How did you fix ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS?