# using HTTPS rather HTTP in some URLs in Grails

Tags: grails

In Grails, I'm using Spring Security Core plugin and I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to make the browser use HTTPS in specific URLs rather HTTP? I'm using this in **Config** file, but it's not working: `grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true`
2. How after login the user will go back to the original requested page, for example, the user is trying to access "securedPage" and this needs to be logged in first to it's redirect to the login page so after login I want the user to go back to that page.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this?

```
grails run-app -https // with HTTPS
```

You can also try using:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
  '/path/**':         'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
]
```

or try using this plugin:

https://grails.org/plugin/force-ssl

Comment: Ya , i know this to run the whole application in HTTPS ,what i need to run some specific URLs in HTTPS

Comment: Any recommendations ?

Comment: I've got two one is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534844/how-to-force-https

Comment: Hi i configured this in the Config file , but when i'm trying to access the URL i defined that requires secure channel i get **this page can't be displayed** , i reviewed https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/channelSecurity.html , is there any configuration in need to do ?

Comment: you may need to remove the s in plugins